# R - How to create a binned/grouped bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is my first ever question on stackoverflow and I am new to R programming. I am trying to create a grouped or binned bar chart in R + ggplot2 with the following data set. 'Customer Count' would be on x axis and 'Value' on y axis. I want to show bars with count intervals such as 0-5, 5-10 etc and I would like to be able to change the intervals to understand the change in distribution of y values.

The table below is aggregation of raw data summarized using dplyr group_by and summarise functions. In my raw data set I have several records and each record has a customer count and a value.

Thanks in advance.

```
Customer Value
Count
    1   93395
    2   116400
    3   133173
    4   64496
    5   252194
    6   106612
    7   24282
    8   67565
    9   11757
    10  131756
    11  58725
    12  53964
    13  28324
    14  91502
    15  41308
    16  14230
    17  55088
    18  17936
    19  43911
    20  50443
    21  30714
    22  3652
    23  22767
    24  845
    25  760
    26  15109
    27  6929
    28  4740
    29  1871
    30  600
    31  9449
    32  473
    33  4896
    34  545
    36  36
    37  54
    38  510
    39  536
    40  151
    41  93
    42  156
    43  3996
    45  103
    46  21
    47  40
```

Comment: Are these aggregations of something else? You're talking about a histogram, but a histogram is a one-variable graph. You could use `cut` to make a grouping variable, but it's easier just to graph the original data with `geom_histogram`.

Comment: If all you have are the binned counts, rather than the raw data, you could do something like this: `ggplot(data.frame(x=rep(dat$Count, dat$Value)), aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,50,5), fill="grey70", color="black")`, where I've assumed the data frame in your question is called `dat`.

Comment: I do have the raw data as well. And yes, these are aggregations of raw data, prepared using using dplyr group_by and summarise functions.

Comment: Then you can do: `ggplot(df, aes(value)) + geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,50,5))`, where I've assumed your data frame is called `df` and `value` is the column you want to aggregate.